# Target js files for specific version of IE with ~sitecollection token

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 publishing site, I have to make some fixes for Internet explorer 7 and 8, I am using following tags to target IE version.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/MySite/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
  <link href="/_catalogs/masterpage/MySite/CSS/iefix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

and it is working fine but I want to add "~sitecollection" token to make sure it works under any site collection url, I have used following tag

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MySite/Scripts/respond.min.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
<![endif]-->
```

but looks like sharepoint control does not work if condition, I can see javascript file in all version of IE, "SharePoint:CssRegistration" has a conditional expression property, Is tehre any equiveloent property for "SharePoint:ScriptLink"